# Can I use Matlab simulink 3D Animation as a 3D CG viewer?

Tags: matlab, 3d, simulink

Simulink 3D Animation is a toolbox for simulink. I read the documentation of it and understood that you can load popular 3D CG data into it and view it at least statically, with some programming in matlab.
Assume I have loaded some 3D object into Simulink 3D Animation successfully. Then Can I rotate the 3D object or do other standard operation on it without programming in Simulink 3D Animation or matlab? For example, I expect it has a rotate buttons to let me rotate the 3D object.

As the second minor question, can you use Simulink 3D animation when you have only matlab but simulink?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: seems like you should get a trial version and try it out - or [watch some videos](http://www.mathworks.com/products/3d-animation/videos.html). It is a minor toolbox, I don't think there are many people around here which can answer that question. Is it actually possible to get Matlab without Simulink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, despite the name, Simulink 3D Animation works with MATLAB only, without Simulink (see [System requirements](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/availability/#VR)).

For the rest, I would go with @thewaywewalk' suggestion, and try it out and/or watch some videos or webinars.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using MATLAB 3D Animation Toolbox for object detection and tracking with an Unmanned Aerial Vehicle.

PAPER:https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9373417

CODE:https://github.com/gsilano/MAT-Fly